# Making a copy of a page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a page and my requirement is that i need one more page with 90% same functionality.

So I wanted to ask if there is any direct method that we can directly create a page with all the functionality of the other page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Manage Content and Structure" and  use the functionality to copy an item.[image]